# Did prophet isa a.s get the injil at 33 year or when he returns

Tags: prophets, prophet-isa

I'm confused did jesus a.s get the injil when was 33 year old before his he get sent to heaven or when he returns? And if he get it when returns then why allah swt say he sent the injil even tho not yet?

Answer (score 0):

He was already sent the Injil:

"And We sent, following in their footsteps, Isa, the son of Maryam, confirming that which came before him in the Torah; and We gave him the Injil, in which was guidance and light and confirming that which preceded it of the Torah as guidance and instruction for the righteous."
-Surah Maidah verse 46

We don't know the age he was given it though, the age 33 for Prophet Isa was from the Bible.

Comment: Tysm Allah swt is the most merciful and most forgiving may Allah swt guide to Islam and forgive all you sins make you go jannat al firadus highest rank of heaven and you family and friends as well may Allah swt guide them both and you aswell Ameen❤❤❤❤❤❤❤❤

Comment: Ameen and you're welcome